# Java Swing - Draw an arc using Graphics.DrawArc(...) on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw an arc on Jpanel in swing from user input having the center of arc, starting point and end point of arc. 
here is my current

```
int x1 = 300; //start point
int y1 = 300;
int x2 = 350; //center point of arc
int y2 = 350;
int x3 = 300; //end point of arc
int y3 = 400;
int h1 = y1 - y2; //calculate with and height from start-center and center-end
int d1 = x2 - x1;
int h2 = y2 - y3;
int d2 = x3 - x2;
int startangle = (int)(Math.atan(h1 / d1) * 180 / Math.PI);
if (x2 > x1 && y2 > y1) {
 startangle = 180 - startangle;
} else if (x2 < x1) {
 //change sign
} else if (y1 < y2) {
 //change sign
}
System.out.println("x1,y1\n" + x1 + "\n" + y1 + "\n" + d2 / h2 + "\n" + Math.atan(d2 / h2) * 180 / Math.PI);
int endangle = (int)(Math.atan2(x3, y3) * 180 / Math.PI);
System.out.println("args: " + "\n" + x2 + "\n" + y2 + "\n" + startangle + "\n" + endangle + "\n");
g2.drawArc(x1, y1, d1, h1, startangle, startangle);
g2.drawArc(x2, y2, d2, h2, 0, endangle);
```

However i am not getting the arc on screen, literally nothing related to it (other shapes work but not this one). No errors or exceptions were thrown.

Edit: Thanks to @MadProgrammer's comment, i am getting a shape but not what i expect.

What i get:
[image: two not connected arcs]
What i expect from the same set of coordinates:
[image]

Edit 2: managed to make it work by using a bezier curve instead of an arc

Comment: Your `width` an `height` (`h1` and `h2` and `d2`) are negative, `Graphics2D` doesn't work with negative width/height values

Comment: What about the angles, are they correct? (I doubt them)

Comment: Well, I don’t know why you’re using startangle for both the start and end position, and based on what you’re trying to do, maybe a  brazier curve might produce a better solution

Comment: I am not sure, was thinking that the point had a startangle and it moves startangle relative  to its initial distance. It turned out to be false, tried a few other ideas, not what i wanted so i just left it as is.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data.

Comment: Please answer your question below, not as an edit to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using a bezier curve and drawing quadcurve in two phases (start-middle,middle-end) using the calculated control points instead of the drawArc method.

Answer (score -2):

I think the bounding rectangle of drawarc is the height and width of the ellipse that your arc is part of.